# What are typical ratios of galley carts to passengers?

Tags: airline-operations, cabin

What are typical ratios for the number of galley carts to passengers on a two meal long haul flight for First, Business, Premium Economy and Economy? This is for cabin layout planning. I found one a/c lessor using 1.0 for First, 0.41 for Business, 0.13 for Premium Economy and 0.1 for Economy. Is that about right?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Maybe you want to clarify your question a bit. Which galley cart sizes are you talking about? Your numbers seem pretty low for a full size trolley - only 20 meals in an Economy cart?

Comment: A full size ATLAS cart has 13 inserts on each side (front and rear). What does the "0.1 for Economy" in your question refer to?

Comment: Thank you for responding. The 0.1 for Economy means that one trolley cart feeds 10 Economy class passengers two meals on a 2 meal long haul flight. Similarly 0.41 for Business Class, means that one trolley cart feeds 2.5 business class passengers on such a flight.